# UIView touchesBegan:withEvent: respond AND forward

Tags: ios, uiview, touchesbegan

I have a `UIView` overlaying a UIViewController. I want to receive all touches and hide the view but still have all underlying controls respond as per usual.

I am using `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and receiving the touches no problem.

I can forward the touches using `pointInside:withEvent:`.

However I can't receive and foward at the same time, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - I landed up putting the a call to my method inside the `pointInside:withEvent:` method before returning. It now picks up all touches underneath the view and performs my method.